# Помогите написать решение уравнения на C#

Tags: c#

Есть задание решить на C# уравнение. Попытался сделать самостоятельно, но выдает ошибку. Свой код прилагаю.

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Введите x: ");
double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите y: ");
double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

double z1n = Math.Pow(Math.Cos(x), 4) + Math.Pow(Math.Sin(y), 2);
double z1v = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(1 / 4), 2) * 2 * x - 1;
double z1 = z1n * z1v;

double z2n = Math.Sin(y + x) * Math.Sin(y - x);
Console.WriteLine(z1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я поправил, но, пожалуйста, в следующий раз потрудитесь сами повернуть картинку на 90 градусов

Comment: `но выдает ошибку` если не секрет, то какую?

Comment: подсвечивает первый writeline и говорит, что только одна единица компиляции может содержать инструкции верхнего уровня.

Comment: ну вы наверное пишите код не в файле Program.cs, где разрешены top-level конструкции

Comment: заработало, спасибо огромное. Я действительно не там писал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, давайте по порядку.

1. Судя по коду, то что вы пытаетесь сделать это не "решение уравнения на C#". Вам нужно просто вычислить значение двух функций
2. Вы не правильно переписали функцию с помощью C#

Вы (честно говоря, без понятия зачем) разбили функцию `z1` на 2 части:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`z1n` вы переписали верно как

```cs
Math.Pow(Math.Cos(x), 4) + Math.Pow(Math.Sin(y), 2)
```

а вот с `z1v` у вас вышло несколько ошибок.

Вы переписали `z1v` так:

```cs
Math.Pow(Math.Sin(1 / 4), 2) * 2 * x - 1
```

что представляет на самом деле следующую формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы перепутали множитель и аргумент. Давайте поставим их на свои места. Вот что выйдет:

```cs
1 / 4 * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(2 * x), 2) - 1
```

Уже лучше, но и этот код не до конца правильный. Все числа без суффиксов в C# интерпретируются как целые, а в целочисленной математике `1 / 4 = 0`. Давайте сделаем их дробными (достаточно одно из них):

```cs
1 / 4d * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(2 * x), 2) - 1
```

С этим разобрались. Далее нам нужно обе части сложить, так как в уравнении плюс:

```cs
double z1 = z1n + z1v
```

у вас же тут, по какой-то причине, стоит знак умножения.

`z2` вы рассчитали верно, только, забыли вывести в консоль.

---

P.S.

Можно добавить сверху

```cs
using static System.Math;
```

и после этого вы сможете использовать методы, по-типу, `Pow` без `Math.`, что сократит код и сделает его более простым к прочтению.

Comment: спасибо огромное. Безмерно благодарен.

Comment: @uwelup безмерно благодарные ставят лайк ответу и отмечают его как принятый